# How to Customize the JMenuBar with HTML code

Tags: java, html, swing, jmenubar

I want to customize The JMenuBar(Available in Swing Package) with the Html and CSS code.I have a small Doubt Whether is it possible.If possible How can I Do the above.Thanks in Advance.

Sample HTML Code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"    "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="en" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<title></title>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html" />
<!-- Begin Vista-Buttons.com HEAD SECTION id=vbUL_cpjbq-->
<style type="text/css">A#vbUL_cpjbqa{display:none}</style>
<!-- End Vista-Buttons.com HEAD SECTION -->
</head>
<body>
<!-- Begin Vista-Buttons.com BODY SECTION id=vbUL_cpjbq-->
<table id="vista-buttons_com_idcpjbq" width="0" cellpadding="0"  cellspacing="0" border="0"><tr></tr></table><script type="text/javascript"> var vbImgPath="menu-files/"</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="menu-files/sccpjbq.js"></script>
<a id="vbUL_cpjbqa" href="http://vista-buttons.com">Right Button Menu by Vista- Buttons.com v5.7</a>
<!-- End Vista-Buttons.com BODY SECTION -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: possible "with with the Html and CSS" <= ver3.2

Comment: It means JDK<=3.2 version !,Now,possible to customize the JMenuBar?

Comment: not Java for Swing to supports Html 3.2 with reduced css

Comment: I want to design a Menu bar with Glossy Nature.Glossy nature is possible to developed by using HTML and CSS.Can I replace the Glossy menu bar the Predefined JMenuBar then add to JFrame.Is the above process is possible? or Is there any way to develop Glossy Menu Bar by using Java.